# A C program does not work when input number is too large

Tags: c, algorithm, memory, memory-management, types

I wrote a program in C that prints English that represents input number (digit by digit)
for example, when you enter `938`, it will print out `nine three eight`
It doesn't work when the input gets too large (more than 9 digits).
Can anyone explain to me why this happens?
I have tried to use unsigned int instead of int for the variables, but it still does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/**
10/17/2012
Programming in C
Ch6 no. 6
Program doesn't work when number gets too large (>9 digits)
Print english that represents input number (digit by digit)
*/

int main(void){

int digit;//use to hold digit

int number;//hold input number

int revNumber = 0; //the reversed digit of the input number

int no_zero = 0;//number of zero needed to be printed at the end

int i = 1;//hold how many digits does the number have (+1 = i*10)

printf("Please enter a number\n");

scanf("%u", &number);

int testing = number;//a copy of input number for

//counts how many digits does the number have (+1 = i*10)

for(; testing != 0;i *= 10){

    testing /= 10;

}

//make the reversed number

do{

    i /= 10;

    digit = number % 10;

    if(digit == 0)

        no_zero++;

    revNumber += (digit*i);

    number /= 10;

}while(number != 0);


//print the result using the reversed number

do{

    digit = revNumber % 10;

    revNumber /= 10;

    switch(digit)

    {

     case 0:

     printf("zero ");

     no_zero--; //minus zero not at the end

     break;

     case 1:

     printf("one ");

     break;

     case 2:

     printf("two ");

     break;

     case 3:

     printf("three ");

     break;

     case 4:

     printf("four ");

     break;

     case 5:

     printf("five ");

     break;

     case 6:

     printf("six ");

     break;

     case 7:

     printf("seven ");

     break;

     case 8:

     printf("eight ");

     break;

     default:

     printf("nine ");

    }

}while(revNumber != 0);


//add back the ending zero

for(;no_zero!=0;no_zero--)

printf("zero ");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: 9 digits is about the limit of a 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 3):

The standard representation of `int`s in C is limited. Basically, you have `8 * sizeof (int)` bits available (let's say `32`). Having `32` bits available, an `unsigned int` can be as large as `2^32 - 1` which is `4294967295` any number greater than this is not ok.

You can try with `unsigned long long` but this would still be limited. Or, you can try using the [BigNum](http://gmplib.org/) library.

**However**, for your specific problem, reading the number as a string and acting on each letter of this string should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

An `int` can (usually) only hold a 32-bit number, so it is limited to storing numbers in the range `[-2147483648, 2147483647]`. So, it can work for any 9 digit number, but fails for most 10-digit numbers.

Instead of putting the number in an `int`, why don't you just read each digit one-at-a-time (with, e.g. `getc`) and process them separately? Then you can handle numbers of any size easily, without needing to use strings.

Comment: The 32 depends on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

From what i gather, you don't really need to store it in a `int`. Store it as a string `(char[])` and then display each digit.

You can infact remove the array entirely and just print the word representation of each digit while it is being entered then discard it.

Answer (score 0):

An integer consists of 32 bits. If you enter a number greater than 2^32, it won't work. Try getting a string from the user instead of an integer.

You can also use *unsigned long long int* which is a 64-bit variable.

Comment: The 32 and the 64 depend on the platform.