# Input the number of more than 20 digits in C languange

Tags: c

Does anyone know how can C read a number that have more than 20 digits ?

I want to input the number that have constraints
between 1  and 10¹⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰ (which is probably have more than 50 digits)

What data type should i use ?

Comment: check out bignum.c https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/algorist/book/programs/bignum.c

Comment: There is no built-in data type you can use.  You will have to write your own code, or use an external library.  One popular one is [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: 10^100000 is an almost impossibly big number!  It has *way* more than 50 digits. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A C program does not work when input number is too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928060/a-c-program-does-not-work-when-input-number-is-too-large)

Answer (score 2):

C has no standard types specified to support numbers of 20 decimal digits (has you ask about in the title) or 50 digits (as you mention later) or 100,000 digits (as numbers up to 10<sup>100,000</sup> require).

You can read user input as sequences of characters, and you can write code to change those codes into digits and to manipulate sequences of digits as decimal numerals as we were all taught in elementary school. You can also use third-party packages such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org) to work with large numbers.

If you are working on some online-judge or other challenge problem that apparently involves numbers up to 10<sup>100,000</sup>, then you should be aware that such problems often have, by design, alternate methods of computing their required results that do not require use of large numbers.